# Retarded Solutions for the Fields: Jefimenko’s Generalizations (Jackson-Electrodynamics)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, vectors, calculus

On p.247 of the textbook, the author claimed we have to make some correction to move the gradient operator outside the bracket.

[image]

How does the first equation (6.53) happen?

$$
[\nabla' \rho]_{ret} = \nabla'[\rho]_{ret} - \left[ \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t'} \right]_{ret} \nabla'(t - R/c)~?\tag{6.53}
$$

I saw there was a related Phys.SE [answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/176919/). But I don't know why this equation provided by the answer is valid.

$$
\left(\sum_i \frac{\partial }{\partial x_i'} \hat{i}\right)[\rho(x_i',x_j',x_k',t')]_{ret} = \left \lbrace \sum_i \left(\frac{\partial x_i'}{\partial x_i'}\frac{\partial }{\partial x_i'} + \frac{\partial x_j'}{\partial x_i'}\frac{\partial }{\partial x_j'} + \frac{\partial x_k'}{\partial x_i'}\frac{\partial }{\partial x_k'} + \frac{\partial t'}{\partial x_i'}\frac{\partial }{\partial t'}\right) \hat{i}\right\rbrace[\rho(x_i',x_j',x_k',t')]_{ret}.
$$

Could you give me a step-by-step derivation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just the chain rule. If $\mathbf{g}$ and $h$ are functions of $\mathbf{r}$ and $t$, and the function $\rho(\mathbf{r}, t)$ means $f(\mathbf{g}(\mathbf{r}, t), h(\mathbf{r}, t)$), then

\begin{equation}
\partial_i \rho = (\nabla f)(\mathbf{g}, h)  \cdot \partial_i \mathbf{g} + (\partial_t f)(\mathbf{g}, h) \, \partial_i h
\end{equation}

You can use this to get any one component of $\nabla' \rho(\mathbf{r}', t - |\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r}'|)$ and then combine the three components into a single vector expression.

Comment: Should the RHS of your first equation be a total derivative?

Comment: @IvanaGyro It is not clear to me which partial derivative you think is supposed to be a total derivative.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the LHS: $\partial_i (g, h)$. Should it be a total derivative?

Comment: @IvanaGyro I guess so, yeah. I prefer to think of it as the partial derivative of the composition.

Comment: Thank you for answering.

Comment: I have now edited the answer to avoid the confusion.