# Why is the expression for the electric field vector on a point in space originating from a moving point charge this way?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, electric-fields

I was studying light as electromagnetic radiation in Feynmann's lectures book (Vol. 1, Ch. 28) and, in explaning how radiation works, he gives the following expression for the electric field at a point in space generated by a moving point charge :

[image]

In most references i could find, the expression for the electric field only takes the first term, which originates from Coloumb's law:

[image]

My questions then are, where does the expression given by Feynmann come from, or how can it be proved? And are there any references that give an explanation/derivation for it?

Thanks for the help.

References for the images:

(1) 28 - Electromagnetic Radiation. https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_28.html

(2) Electric Field due to a Uniformly Charged Ring. https://medium.com/swlh/electric-field-due-to-a-uniformly-charged-ring-6b0adcbf7b8d

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jefimenko%27s_equations

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/176919/derivation-of-jefimenkos-equation-in-jacksons-emt-book

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to write equations rather than posting images of them.